# Scrollview not working on localization in ios

Tags: ios, localization, uiscrollview

I am using localization in iphone application with nib files and not with storyboard. In the application there are two languages used and languages can be switched at any point of the application. In that I maually changing the xibs in the view controller in the button click using the below code :

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@”en” ofType:@"lproj"];
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
NSArray *objects = [bundle loadNibNamed:@"MyViewController" owner:self options:nil];
self.view = (UIView *) [objects objectAtIndex:0];
```

In the two xibs there is a scrollview inside the uiview and a single iboutlet for scrollview. In that scrollview there is a label, imageview and a table view. When the view controller loads first time it works fine for both languages, but when the language is switched the scrollview is not working.

I don't know how to set the scrollview.

Comment: Have you added the localization in the project settings? And have you added your label, imageview and table view to your containerview(UIView) and added your container view to your scroll view set the content size of the scroll view is the size of your contentview?

Answer (score 0):

> - (void)viewDidLoad {
>
>   [super viewDidLoad];
>
>   // Set up the container view to hold your custom view hierarchy
>
>   CGSize containerSize = CGSizeMake(320.0f, 640.0f);
>
>   self.containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f),
>     .size=containerSize}];
>
>   [self.scrollView addSubview:self.containerView];
>
>   // Set up your custom view hierarchy
>     UILabel *mylabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 640.0f, 80.0f)];
>
>   [self.containerView mylabel];
>
>   UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160.0f, 160.0f, 320.0f, 320.0f)];
>
>   [myImageView setBackGroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
>
>   [self.containerView addSubview:myImageView];
>
>   // Tell the scroll view the size of the contents
>     self.scrollView.contentSize = containerSize; }

Comment: I added the content size in the view did appear method since it does not work when we set the content size in the view did load or view will appear.Its working for the first time .But when we click the button to change the language ie, changing the xib.,scroll view  not working.

Comment: There is a navigation bar button to change the language . In that button click,the above code                                      NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@”en” ofType:@"lproj"];
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
NSArray *objects = [bundle loadNibNamed:@"MyViewController" owner:self options:nil];
self.view = (UIView *) [objects objectAtIndex:0]; With this am switching the xib and setting the language using this -> NSString *currentLn = [arbundle localizedStringForKey:@"en" value:@"en" table:@"localizedString"];

Comment: in the above code i missed to give code for arbundle: arbundle is  ->  NSString *arpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"];
    NSBundle *arbundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:arpath];
    NSString *currentLn = [arbundle localizedStringForKey:@"en" value:@"en" table:@"localizedString"];